# Location using FusedLocationAPI in Android

Tags: android, location

I am trying to get location using new Google Service API. I am trying out the following:

```
PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates
                (mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

with the following configration:

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Where INTERVAL AND FASTEST INTERVAL is:

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
```

The results are coming up properly. Now question is that Is FusedLocationAPI the best way to get Location?

Also will this setup work in all types of problems:

1. when the user is checking the location the first time on his phone - Installing my App and hasn't got the location any time?
2. When user has no internet on phone? (This works fine on Nexus 5)
3. When user has airplane mode ON and has WIFI ON? (This works fine on Nexus 5)
4. Is there any issues with FusedLocationAPI? Any drawback?

Answer (score 0):

> when the user is checking the location the first time on his phone -
> Installing my App and hasn't got the location any time?

When user open play store or any google service it will start location service. you can check in running service > google play service > location service. so it will get location on the basis of network or GPS. so you don't have to worry about last location.

> When user has no internet on phone? (This works fine on Nexus 5)
>
> When user has airplane mode ON and has WIFI ON? (This works fine on
> Nexus 5)

if device has never connected to internet then it will give null value but if it is connected even once with proper bandwidth it has location data.

> Is there any issues with FusedLocationAPI? Any drawback?

As it is **Google API** it can be changed or removed so it is not in our hand. plus it totally depends upon device play store and version so if device have older version of play service then your package version some time you will see weird output also.

Hope it will clear your doubts and other things already mentioned in doc so you can check it also.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answers. What is the best way to get Location then?

Comment: @SanjanaNair Right now it is good api can't say about best but they have handled core functionality of android location manager(too much boilerplate code required)  with some shared preference and callbacks. if you can create your own full proof implementation then it is best.